# how can calculate the price for 5 days (hotel booking system)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a hotel booking system, when the user chooses the start date and end date for staying in the hotel, I want to give the total price:

For example: when the user chooses Start date: 2013-08-01, to : 2013-08-11 (two season default, and high season) also the price of days is different.

---

This is my table:

[image]

How can write a SQL command (MySQL) or do I need to use PHP code?

Comment: Sum function should work a treat.

Comment: maybe need to change table strcture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure is not set up to do this very efficiently.  However, it is still possible.

I would start by splitting out each date of the stay separately.  Join this to the rates table.  Then use a big case statement based on day of the week to get the rate.  If there is no match in the rate table, then use the default rate:

```
select sum(case when dayname(thedate) = 'Monday' then coalesce(r.MonPrice, def.MonPrice)
                when dayname(thedate) = 'Tuesday' then coalesce(r.TuePrice, def.TuePrice)
                . . .
                when dayname(thedate) = 'Sunday' then coalesce(r.SunPrice, def.SunPrice) as TotalPrice
from (select strtodate('2013-08-01', '%Y-%m-%d') as thedate union all
      select strtodate('2013-08-02', '%Y-%m-%d') union all
      . . . 
      select strtodate('2013-08-11', '%Y-%m-%d')
     ) dates left outer join
     Rates r
     on dates.thedate between r.date_to and r.date_from cross join
     Rates def
     on def.season_price = 'default'
```

In this example, I've the dates are each put into a subquery.  There are other ways to do this, but since you are constructing the query in php, this might be the easiest solution.

The "..." mean to add similar SQL code, since "..." is not recognized as part of SQL.

Comment: thank you very much , but what is the perfect structure for the table  , because I want it will be very efficiently

Comment: A much better structure for the table would be to have rows defined by <hotel>, <day of week>, and <season_price>.  This would simplify much of the code.

Comment: You mean the columns will be like this ( ID , id_hotel , season_name ,  id_room , Saturday , Sunday , Monday , Tuesday , Wednesday , Thursday , Friday )

Comment: No, the columns would be id, id_hotel, season_name, id_room, DayOfWeek.

Comment: but the weekend will be more expensive than other days , Sat , Sun will be = 200 , and other days will be= 150

Comment: the DayOfweek it is varchar ( type )

Comment: @bosami . . . That is why you would have a separate row for each dow of the week, 7 in total for each hotel/season combination.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no SQL expert but what I'd do is to write Stored Procedure which would

1. find all the dates within the range. see fill_calendar at http://www.richnetapps.com/using-mysql-generate-daily-sales-reports-filled-gaps/
2. for each day within the range, check the DAYOFWEEK (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
   Val1,
   Val2,
   Val3,
   (Val1 + Val2 + Val3) as 'Total'
FROM Emp
```

or if you just want one row:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(Val1) as 'Val1',
   SUM(Val2) as 'Val2',
   SUM(Val3) as 'Val3',
   (SUM(Val1) + SUM(Val2) + SUM(Val3)) as 'Total'
FROM Emp
```

Comment: I hope that helps, also this question is quite common on Stack Overflow, the search function works well.

Comment: The tricky part is that it depends on the starting day, f.e. monday will have different price than sunday

Comment: sorry for downvoting, but I believe the author doesn't ask how to sum some trivial values. as you can see, you need to calculate the price for every day within the given range, taking the proper price for monday, tusday etc.

Comment: thanks Supplement , migajek is right ^_^